# Unable to present total with Grid view's ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am following the same tutorial as the in this post:

[shoppingcart using gridview asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499201/shoppingcart-using-gridview-asp-net)

The tutorials page: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/shopping-cart

However I get a different error, and I don't understand why. When I run the application it works to the point where I get this exception message:

**"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_ia5agzom.dll but was not handled in user code"**

and it points to the following line in ShoppingCart.aspx :

```
<%# String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.Product.UnitPrice))) %>
```

Which if I remove the program runs, but does not show the price per unit.

My code is as follows:

**ShoppingCart.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FrontEnd.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShoppingCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="Gbl.UserPages.ShoppingCart" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
    <div id="ShoppingCartTitle" runat="server" class="ContentHead"><h1>Shopping Cart</h1></div>
    <asp:GridView ID="CartList" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ShowFooter="True" 
        GridLines="Vertical" 
        CellPadding="4"
        ItemType="Gbl.Models.CartItem" 
        SelectMethod="GetShoppingCartItems"
        CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" >   
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ProductId" />        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.ProductName" HeaderText="Name" />        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product.UnitPrice" HeaderText="Price (each)" DataFormatString="{0:c}"/>     
        <asp:TemplateField   HeaderText="Quantity">            
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PurchaseQuantity" Width="40" runat="server" Text="<%#: Item.Quantity %>"></asp:TextBox> 
                </ItemTemplate>        
        </asp:TemplateField>    
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">            
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.Product.UnitPrice))) %>
                </ItemTemplate>        
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove Item">            
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="Remove" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>        
        </asp:TemplateField>    
        </Columns>    
    </asp:GridView>
    <div>
        <p></p>
        <strong>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelTotalText" runat="server" Text="Order Total: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
        </strong> 
    </div>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class ShoppingCart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ShoppingCartEngine usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartEngine())
            {
                decimal cartTotal = 0;
                cartTotal = usersShoppingCart.GetTotal();
                if (cartTotal > 0)
                {
                    // Display Total.
                    lblTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", cartTotal);

                }
                else
                {
                    LabelTotalText.Text = "labeltotaltext";
                    lblTotal.Text = "labeltotal";

                    ShoppingCartTitle.InnerText = "Shopping Cart is Empty";
                }
            }
        }

        public List<CartItem> GetShoppingCartItems()
        {
            ShoppingCartEngine engine = new ShoppingCartEngine();
            return engine.GetCartItems();
        }
    }
```

**CardItem.cs:**

```
public class CartItem
{
    [Key]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my **stack trace:**

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP.userpages_shoppingcart_aspx.__DataBind__control17(Object sender, EventArgs e) in i:\gabriel\work\school\civ_eng\gral_workspaces\visualstudio2014_ASP.NET\assignment_2\Gbl\UserPages\ShoppingCart.aspx:25
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +85
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +187
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +94
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +187
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +94
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +15
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3724
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +123
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Which line of code is it failing on?

Comment: @Rick S Hi there, I have just edited and pointed out the faulting line, it looks as if the price was not set but it is...

Comment: Are you sure that all items have a product?  i.e. Item.Product is not null.

Comment: I am copying and pasting the AddToCart(int id) method in the tutorial, in the link above at the "Creating the Shopping Cart Class" section.. and the there it is created, but it certainly looks as if it is not working... can it be something else? if I remove Convert.ToDouble(...) in the faulting line the error is gone

Comment: If take out the offending code do you see values in the columns for price, product name and quantity?

Comment: If I remove the part at the offending line  Convert.ToDouble(...) then I only see |ID|Quantity|Item|Total|RemoveItem| but it is missing |Name| and |Price|

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial that line should include UnitPrice not Price:

```
<%#: String.Format("{0:c}", ((Convert.ToDouble(Item.Quantity)) *  Convert.ToDouble(Item.Product.UnitPrice)))%>
```

Comment: But in my entity class for product I had written Price

Comment: If you're changing code from the tutorial then i probably won't be able to help you.

Comment: Okay I will change it back then.. I had io mind expanding it later, but I can do that after I sort this out.

Comment: I have reverted to the original but it does not work anyway... But it is the price and the name of the product what does not show up.

Comment: It's too bad they don't have a way to download the whole project so you don't have to copy/paste.

Comment: I actually have found a way to download it, but I rather type, I will look into it and re-do it. In any case, I think it has to do with the way the items are added to the cart and the session key which influences on how the total is calculated

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable lazy loading Product needs to be set to virtual:

```
 public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

So the entity class should look like this:

public class CartItem
{

```
[Key]
public string CartItemId { get; set; }

public string CartId { get; set; }

public int ProductId { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }

public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

}